# last non-empty row of another sheets, how *row() works?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=INDEX(Jun!C:C, MAX((Jun!C:C<>"")*ROW(Jun!C:C)))
```

Above is what I found on the web. With this formula, I can get the value of the last row in sheet `Jun`.

Could you explain how `MAX((Jun!C:C<>"")*ROW(Jun!C:C))` works? I tried to study it alone but merely got a constant value of 1. It means only when it was put inside `INDEX` can work as we expect.

Comment: ```Jun!C:C<>""``` returns an array of ```TRUE``` (if the cell is not empty) and  ```FALSE``` (if the cell is empty), in excel and google sheet, ```TRUE``` is equal to ```1```, and ```FALSE``` is equal to ```0```. ```ROW()``` returns the ```INDEX``` of a ```ROW``` as number. When any number times ```0``` (```FALSE```) returns ```0```, so ```(Jun!C:C<>"")*ROW(Jun!C:C)``` will return an array with the length of ```Jun!C:C ``` whitch contains ```Zeros``` for empty cells and ```ROW INDEX``` of non-empty cells, ```MAX()``` returns the biggest number of an array, the index of last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us break down the formula:

```
=index(Jun!C:C, max((Jun!C:C<>"") * row(Jun!C:C)))
```

...like this:

<sup>1</sup>`=index(` <sup>2</sup>`Jun!C:C,` <sup>3</sup>`max(` <sup>4</sup>`(Jun!C:C<>"")` `*` <sup>5</sup>`row(Jun!C:C)` `)` `)`

<sup>1</sup>`index()` is an array enabling function which means that the expressions in it will be evaluated for *all rows* and *all columns* in the ranges given as parameters to the function, one row and one column at a time. The function only gets to do its thing when all parameters have been evaluated, at which time it returns the value in <sup>2</sup>`Jun!C:C` whose row number is given by the <sup>3</sup>`max()`.

<sup>4</sup>`(Jun!C:C<>"")` is an expression that will give `true` on rows that contain a value and `false` on empty rows. Since it is evaluated in an array formula context here, it will obtain as many results as there are rows in `Jun!C:C`, giving a vertical array of [Booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type).

<sup>5</sup>`row(Jun!C:C)` is an expression that returns row numbers. In this array formula, it will return a vertical array that contains 1, 2, 3... all the way up to the row number of the last row in `Jun!C:C`.

Next, the `*` operator multiplies the Booleans given by (<sup>4</sup>) by the row numbers given by (<sup>5</sup>), in pairs. In the Boolean array, `false` is automatically coerced to `0` and `true` is coerced to `1` when accessed by a mathematical operator such as `*` . The multiplication of these Booleans and row numbers gives a vertical array like 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0... Many of these results will be zero because all blank rows will yield a product of `0` because `(Jun!C:C<>"")` is `false` on such rows.

(<sup>3</sup>)`max()` then picks the largest result among those products. That number corresponds with the row number of the last row that is not blank.

(<sup>1</sup>)`index()` gets the result from `max()` expression as its second parameter, which tells which row to get in the array specified by the first parameter, i.e., in the column (<sup>2</sup>)`Jun!C:C`.

The end result is that the formula gets the value in the last cell that has visible content in column `Jun!C:C`.

My understanding is that the earliest reference to the pattern was in [Sheets Challenge #1](https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/fz-BzXJz454/discussion) in the Google Docs Help Forum in 2015-01-09:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(LEN(TRIM(A:A)),ROW(A:A))))  (44) Yogi
=INDEX(A:A,MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))           (34) --Hyde
=INDEX(LOOKUP(2,IF(A:A<>"",1),A:A))           (34) AD:AM
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(2,IF(A:A<>"",1)))            (33) AD:AM
=SORT(A:A,(A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A),)&""             (32) 2n9
=+SORT(A:A,ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""),0)              (31) Isai
=+SORT(A:A,ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""),)               (30) 2n9
=+SORT(A:A,A:A<>"",,ROW(A:A),)                (29) Isai
```

See the [index()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098242) help page and the [ArrayFormula lab](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/01/16/arrayformula-lab/) blog post by Maxim Makhrov.

Comment: However, if you take =MAX((Jun!C:C<>"")*ROW(Jun!C:C)) alone, it will get an incorrect value, which is always 1. Only when you put it inside the INDEX function can it get a correct value.

Comment: to get the value of =MAX((Jun!C:C<>"")*ROW(Jun!C:C)) alone, I added an auxiliary column which =COUNTA(Jan!C:C).

Comment: To get the row number of the last row with content, use `=arrayformula(max((Jun!C:C<>"") * row(Jun!C:C)))`. The `counta()` function will not get the last row number when there are blank cells between non-blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

To explain what `=INDEX(Jun!C:C, MAX((Jun!C:C<>"")*ROW(Jun!C:C)))` does, you have to understand some basic concepts:

Assume your `A:A` has 5 columns, but only row 1-3 has a value,

| A |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
|  |
|  |

if you put the formula `=ArrayFormula(A:A)` in `B1`, you get this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A1 |
| A2 | A2 |
| A3 | A3 |
|  |  |
|  |  |

`A:A` is an Array, it contains values as the same number as the length of the `A` column,

Now, what happen if we change the formula `=ArrayFormula(A:A)` to `=ArrayFormula(A:A<>"")`?

You get this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | TRUE |
| A2 | TRUE |
| A3 | TRUE |
|  | FALSE |
|  | FALSE |

`<>` in excel and google sheet act as a `NOT operator`, when you type in a formula `A1<>10`, it means you are testing the value in `A1` to see if it is not equal to `10`, if it is 10, you get `FALSE`, if it isn't, you get `TRUE`.

`=ArrayFormula(A:A<>"")` will test every cell in the `A` Column and see if they contains an `EMPTY Value` or not, in Excel and Google sheet, `Empty` is also considered as a kind of value.

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are called `Boolean value`, which in Excel and Google sheet, has the same weight as `1` and `0`, you can tell by warping up `TRUE` or `FALSE` with the `INT()` function, it will return `1` and `0`.

`ROW()` function return the index of a given row, if you apply this formula `=ArrayFormula(ROW(A:A))` to `C` Column of our test data, you will get this result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | TRUE | 1 |
| A2 | TRUE | 2 |
| A3 | TRUE | 3 |
|  | FALSE | 4 |
|  | FALSE | 5 |

As mentioned earlier, `TRUE` and `FALSE` have the same weight as `1` and `0`. A basic Math concept is, when you multiple any number by `1`, it returns the same number, and when you multiple any number by `0`, the result is always `0`.

Now, let's do the calculation in `D` Column by this formula `=ArrayFormula(B:B*C:C)`, this is what you will see:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | TRUE | 1 | 1 |
| A2 | TRUE | 2 | 2 |
| A3 | TRUE | 3 | 3 |
|  | FALSE | 4 | 0 |
|  | FALSE | 5 | 0 |

As you can see, `D4` and `D5` become `0`, since `B4` and `B5` is `FALSE`, and `FALSE` has the same weight as `0`, so when we multiply `B4` and `B5` with `C4` and `C5`, it returns `0`.

finally, `MAX()` function will return the biggest number of an array, so if you put down this formula `=MAX(D1:D5)` somewhere into our sample data, you will get `3` as the result, which means `ROW number 3 is the last row with a value in Column A`.

Comment: =ArrayFormula(A:A<>"") will get an error: Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (10).

Comment: =ArrayFormula((A:A<>"") *  row(A:A)) is okay.

Comment: ```=ArrayFormula(A:A<>"")``` won't return error unless you put it somewhere below ```Row 1```, this formula is testing all values of the ```Column A``` and return a ```TRUE``` or ```FALSE``` in each row as output, which means the return values will always has the same ```length``` as the sheet itself. If you put it below ```Row 1```, the sheet will never has enough empty row to show the result.

Comment: try to stick with the instructions of the demo, did mentioned in descriptions saying " put the formula ```=ArrayFormula(A:A)``` in ```B1```, " and " change the formula ```=ArrayFormula(A:A)``` to ```=ArrayFormula(A:A<>"")``` "

Comment: and of course, check the column where you put down these formulas and see if they are really empty or not, you can make sure a column is empty by simply select the column and press delete.